# How to replace .env file placeholders with deployment variables in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: deployment, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket repository.
I have Deployment environment variables in bitbucket:

```
BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_PORT : 8080
```

In my `bitbucket-pipelines.yaml` script I can Write the variable into the .env file like this:

```
<...>
step: &deploy-to-environment
        name: Deploy to environment
        deployment: environment
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - echo Create .env file
          - echo "PORT=$BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_PORT" > .env          
          - cat .env
<...>
```

But I would like to avoid rewriting the whole lines of .env file.

Is it possible to implement the following?

1. I would like to have .env file with placeholders (.env file content):

```
    <...>
    PORT=<BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_PORT>
    HOST=<BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_HOST>
    <...>
```

2. Replace these placeholders in yaml script section:

```
    <...>
        step: &deploy-to-environment
                name: Deploy to environment
                deployment: environment
                caches:
                  - node
                script:
                  - <replace_placeholders_here_in_script>
    <...>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sed to replace string in .env file

```
sed -i "s/BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_PORT/...xxxx.../" .env
sed -i "s/BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_HOST/...hostname.../" .env
```

You can use also variables for replacement

```
MYPORT=XXX
sed -i "s/BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_PORT/$MYPORT/" .env
```

Comment: I would like to make it more general way without writing a line for each variable replacement.

Comment: The required script should replace any placeholder with appropriate variable from deployment variables. By their names.

Comment: Then provide variables as replacement. You can set variables in deploy utility
MYPORT=xxx
MYHOSTNAME=yyyy

`sed -i "s/BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_PORT/$MYPORT/" .env
sed -i "s/BITBUCKET_VARIABLE_HOST/$MYHOSTNAME/" .env
`

Comment: Is it possible to have all variables and their names in the nodejs script? I mean: npm run myscript. And then have these variables inside js script? Without hard-coded names of the variables in yaml script.

Comment: Make sure to use the `.env` file in artifacts

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I found to do it, you just have to be careful with those echo commands (here I'm making env for firebase but you can swap your bitbucket variables in how you like)

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &Env
            name: Create .env file
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - echo VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY="${VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY}" >> .env
              - echo VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN="${VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}" >> .env
              - echo VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="${VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}" >> .env
              - echo VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET="${VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET}" >> .env
              - echo VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="${VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}" >> .env
              - echo VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID="${VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID}" >> .env
              - more .env
            artifacts:
              - .env         
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *Env
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue lately and didn't want to include 1 by 1 the env variable, what I ended up doing:

#1 Create in repository a .env.example file (This file will hold variable that required for this repository without values or default values that are not sensitive)

```
APP_NAME=MyApp
APP_ENV=
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Then I created a `pipeline.sh`

```sh
echo "[+] Building enviroment variables"

# Get contents of example file
ENV_CONTENT=$(cat ./.env.example)

# Output the content into sh script
echo "#! /bin/bash
echo \"
${ENV_CONTENT}
\"" > ./env.sh

# sed replace as key=${BITBUCKET_ENV_VARIABLE:-default_value_from_example}
sed -i -E "s/^([A-Z_]+)=(.*)$/\1=\${\1:-\2}/g" ./env.sh

chmod +x ./build/env.sh

# Exec the env sh script and output content to .env file
./build/env.sh > ./build/.env
```

So in case you have defined in `.env.example` `APP_NAME` and also defined it in bitbucket Repository Variables the final `.env` will have key `APP_NAME=value_of_bitbucket_variable`